# in function 'inRange' (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty()

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a small project with openCV and I get this **error** message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 115, in <module>
    value = cv2.inRange(roi, (0,0,0), (255, 255, 75)) 
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /root/opencv/opencv-4.1.2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1726: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'inRange'
```

I have already done some research on the Internet, but have not yet found a solution that works for me. The error always occurs when I change the coordinates of the region of interest (short roi).

**Code** (at least the most important parts):

```
roi= (50, 270, 150, 192)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  

    image = frame.array 
    cut = image[roi[0]:roi[1]][roi[2]:roi[3]]
    value = cv2.inRange(cut, (0,0,0), (255, 255, 75))
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution: The problem boils down to a simple Syntax mistake:

It should be

```py
cut = image[roi[0]:roi[1], roi[2]:roi[3]]
```

instead of

```py
cut = image[roi[0]:roi[1]][roi[2]:roi[3]]
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are slicing the axes in the correct order because the
[frame.array](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_array.html#picamera.array.PiArrayOutput.array) returns a numpy array with shape (y,x,3).

> After flush() is called, this attribute contains the frame’s data as a multi-dimensional `numpy array`. This is typically organized with the dimensions (rows, columns, plane). Hence, an **RGB image with dimensions x and y would produce an array with shape (y, x, 3)**.
> Make sure your axes slice are in the right order

```
#RGB Image 640x480
img = np.ones((480,640,3))

roi= (500, 600, 150, 192)

cut = img[roi[0]:roi[1]][roi[2]:roi[3]]
value = cv2.inRange(cut, (0,0,0), (255, 255, 75))

#error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'
```

Comment: So it was just the wrong order of rows and columns? So would roi= (150, 192, 50, 270) be correct?

Comment: According to the error displayed it seems so. You can be sure of the order and size of the array by doing `image.shape`.

Comment: ok, thank you for the tip, my resolution is 320, 192 if that helps. But I will try your command as well

Comment: Edit: image.shapes outputs 192, 320, 3. Butt what do I have to change now in my program? Do you have any experience with the picamera since I run it on a raspberry pi?

Comment: I use picamera in some projects together with the opencv library most of the time to detect and count objects. If these values are the ones returned by the `image.shape`, they seem to be inconsistent with the roi used, `50: 270`, with the y range being `0:191`, but this alone would not cause the problem shown. However, if your `roi` changes dynamically, you must ensure that the start of slicing is within the image area.